# True / false question about a Cauchy sequence in Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I am solving assignments in Real analysis but I am unable to think about how I can solve this question.

> Let $f: ( 0, \infty ) \to \mathbb{R}$  be a continuous function. Does $f$ maps any Cauchy sequence to a Cauchy sequence.

I tried by taking $ {x_n} $ and using |$x_n $ - $x_m$| <$\epsilon$
for all  $n, m > N$ ( $N$ is a natural number) . But how can I formulate the Cauchy sequence property of $x_n$  into $f(x_n$) ? I am unable to think about it.

Any hints please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take the map $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ and the Cauchy sequence $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n \ge 1}$